# Object identifier, return value or variable?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Currently building this hierarchy of objects and to be able to make the logging a bit more clear in the baseclass I decided to have some kind of variable or function that returns the type of the class.

For example:

```
class fruit {
   string _type;

   fruit() {
       _type = "base"; // or i dont have to set it. however, it wont be inforced
   }

   virtual const char* type() const { return "base"; } // or just = 0 to inforce it

   void function() {
       log(this->type(), " tastes good");
       log(this->_type, "tastes good");
   }
}

class apple : public fruit {

   apple() {
       _type = "apple";
   }

   const char* type() const { return "apple"; }
}
```

As you can see there is two approaches and me personally think that the return value version is much cleaner since it is clear that it needs to be implemented.

My question however is what approach is the best one? And is it a lot slower to call a function everytime I'm logging something? Just assumed that it would be optimized but I can be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, If you need to *know* the type of class in your program then there is something wrong in your design. Usually, You wouldn't want to your program to depend on *concrete imlpementations* but to depend on *interfaces*.

Anyhow, the function should be a pure virtual function so that every deriving class must implement it otherwise you would end up getting the wrong types for derived classes if someone doesn't implement it for their derivying class.

Assigning a string and returning a string literal are both fine.
String literals have static storage duration so it will be valid throughout the duration of the program, Also you appropriately have the `const char`return type so that user doesn't modify the returned literal and end up causing an **Undefined Behavior**.
Returning a member is fine as well though it justs add some overhead of an additional member to your class & you are not too worried about this extra member.

Comment: the only thing im using it for is the logging, to make it clear which dervied class im dealing with. i need a char* for that, describing the class. dont see anything wrong with that, do you?

Comment: @chikuba: Looks fine to me in that case.Do note the point about making the function pure virtual.

Comment: not too sure what you ment by "You wouldn't want to your program to depend on concrete imlpementations but to depend on interfaces."

Comment: @chikuba: It is one of the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) design principles, You might want to lookup [The Separation of Interface and Implementation in C++](http://www.architectworkshop.com/martin/papers/Separation.pdf)

Comment: yeah, im aware of that and i dont depend on the implementation in my code.  i was more asking what that has to do with my question.

Comment: @chikuba: My initial comment was an word of caution rather advice, it intended to point out that if your program *logic* depends on knowing the type then it is a bad design, Since you only need it for diagnostic purposes its fine, and I further do explain why.I don't think any aspect to the Question you asked.